# Intercept field access using Java Instrumentation

Tags: java, profiler, instrumentation

I am building a profiler Using Java Instrumentation + Javaassit to intercept all the method, constructor calls. I would also like to intercept the Class Field access (Would like to monitor the static fields data to prevent misuse).

```
Class A {

public static String data = "1";

    public static void main(String[] s) {

        //I would like to intercept this field access
        System.out.println(data);
        //I would like to intercept this field data modification
        data ="2";
    }
}
```

Is this possible to intercept them? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Javassist's [FieldAccess](http://www.javassist.org/html/javassist/expr/FieldAccess.html) has a method replace which replaces the field access with your own code. I suppose this could be used to achieve what you want.

See also http://www.javassist.org/html/javassist/expr/ExprEditor.html